# Added configuration disappears after opening another project in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, configuration

I add a custom Run/Build Gradle Configuration, then close the Android Studio, and then I open the studio again everything works correctly. But when I open another project (in the same window) and then open the first project again the custom Gradle Configuration is gone and I have to create and configurate it again.

Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: I tried reinstalling the studio but it did not help.

Comment: It is ok and everything works correctly after update on Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 16, 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update to Android Studio 3.3.2 or higher